# Set up MongoDB for multiple developers plus production use

Tags: 18.04, docker, mongodb

I've been told that [Docker](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) is the way to go to create user separation from actual production. Is it somehow possible to make further separation and install separate [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/what-is-mongodb) databases without affecting the original?

I'd be happy to learn. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: The question is rather vague here, and the answer might be affected by the exact role played by the MongoDB dataset in the whole project. Can you provide a more precise use case, so that you can get a more precise answer ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can and should. Just create several environments, for example for development, testing, [and for production](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/administration/production-notes/). Just create a Dockerfile for one of each.

One way could be:

1. Create a `Dockerfile` ([the official](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/blob/master/engine/examples/mongodb/Dockerfile) is broken, so I created this one and [a PR](https://github.com/docker/docker.github.io/pull/8987)):

   ```yaml
   # Dockerizing MongoDB: Dockerfile for building MongoDB images
   # Based on ubuntu:18.04, installs MongoDB following the instructions from:
   # http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

   FROM       ubuntu:18.04

   # Installation:
   # Import MongoDB public GPG key AND create a MongoDB list file
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gnupg2 ca-certificates
   RUN apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 9DA31620334BD75D9DCB49F368818C72E52529D4
   RUN echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu bionic/mongodb-org/4.0 multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-4.0.list

   # Update apt-get sources AND install MongoDB (latest stable version)
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mongodb-org

   # Create the MongoDB data directory
   RUN mkdir -p /data/db

   # Expose port #27017 from the container to the host
   EXPOSE 27017

   # Set /usr/bin/mongod as the dockerized entry-point application
   ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod"]
   ```
2. Build

   ```
   docker build --tag my_mongodb_1 .
   ```
3. Run

   ```
   docker run -p 27017:27017 --interactive --tty my_mongodb_1
   ```

---

Pay special attention to which user have access to which environment, since is very common and dangerous to forget to change something on the developer setup and end working with production database thinking you are working with development one.

[Here](https://medium.com/@pablo_ezequiel/creating-a-docker-image-with-mongodb-4c8aa3f828f2) is a nice post about how to do all this.

Comment: Thx for your answer! I wrote this, https://pastebin.com/6j9GHz6x. I am trying to install Python as well. Also, is it good practice to allow each user to use their account to create a container connected with their account? Including a /home/ folder of theirs.

Comment: If you cannot connect to mongodb from Robo 3T on macos, then add --bind_ip_all: `ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/bin/mongod", "--bind_ip_all"]`